# Are Lebesgue measurable sets the only sets for which the outer measure is sigma additive?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

I am currently studying Lebesgue measure theory, and I had some questions about the definition of the Lebesgue measure.

So, to start off, we are looking for a well-defined, positive function $m$ acting on real sets, satisfying

1. For every interval $I$, $m(I)=|I|$ ($I$ is the interval's length).
2. $m(E+x_0)=m(E)$ (invariance to shifts of the set).
3. Sigma additivity: $m(\bigcup_n E_n)=\sum_n E_n$, for disjoint $E_n$.

The outer measure is defined as

$$m^*(E)=\text{inf}\space \{\sum_n |I_n| : E\subset\bigcup I_n \}$$

And it satisfies all requirements, except sigma-additivity (it only satisfies sub-sigma-additivity). It can also be proven that there is no function satisfying all requirements. Therefore, the requirement of acting on *all* real sets is dropped, and we define the Lebesgue measure as the outer measure acting only on "Lebesgue measurable" sets. These are sets $E$, for which for all $A\subset \mathbb{R}$,
$$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c)$$

I have two questions. Firstly, is my understanding of how the Lebesgue measure defined correct? Secondly, if it is, can it be shown that Lebesgue measurable sets are the *only* real sets for which the outer measure is sigma-additive?

I really don't know how to even think about this intuitively, and it might be beyond my competence (or very simple?), but thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking seems correct.

Non-measurable sets can be sigma-additive. Let's consider a Vitali set $V$ (or any other non-measurable set on $[0,1]$) and now consider $\{V+2n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. It's easy to see that these disjoint sets are sigma-additive. in fact you could change it a little bit (appropriately contracting the sets) and get a finite-measure sum as well.
In fact more generally: if we have $dist(A_i, A_j) > M$ for every pair $i \neq j$ and some constant $M>0$ independent from $i, j$, then $A_i$ are sigma additive in Lebesgue measure.

Now an interesting thing is that if you drop the Axiom of Choice, then you can construct a measure stisfying your conditions which is defined on every subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So the existance of non-measurable sets requires the Axiom of Choice. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model.

Comment: But you can add all the sets of infinite measure to the family of measurable sets and preserve aigma additivity for ALL the sets in this bigger family. But such a family is not closed with respect to intersections (see the example I gave with Vitali sets).

Comment: The interesting question is whether you can extend the family of measurable sets by some non-measurable set with a finite measure, in such a way that the resulting bigger family is sigma-additive for all sequences of disjoint sets.

Comment: Is the claim that $m^*(V\cup (V+2n)) = m^*(V)+m^*(V+2n)$?

Comment: We are summing over all the natural numbers, so the claim is about a countable sum. But your claim is true as well.

Comment: I am not sure I understand... Are you saying $E=V\cup (V+2n)$ is a set for which $m^*$, is sigma-additive?

Comment: I'm saying that $m^*(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (V + 2n)) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} m^*(V+2n)$.

Comment: Ohh, I get it.. Thanks!